# .htaccess redirect problems

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, directory

I'm using WordPress on my domain. I originally installed it in a sub-directory:

www.example.com/wpblog/

I have now moved the blog into the root of my site AND I have changed the permalink structure from ../2011/03/name-of-post to ../name-of-post.

I am trying to redirect all links to my blog which use the old URL and structure.

I use this code to successfully redirect from /wpblog/ to the site root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Redirect 301 /wpblog/ http://www.example.com/
```

But now I need to change the OLD permalink structure to remove the /2011/03/, leaving me with www.example.com/name-of-post (from: www.example.com/wpblog/2011/03/name-of-post). I added this code, which works 100%:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$3
```

The trouble is, that also breaks links to my media files (www.example.com/wp-content/2011/03/name-of-media). I therefore need to exclude the /wp-content/ directory from the permalink redirect (but not the /wpblog/ redirect). I changed the permalink redirect thus:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/wp-content/"
RewriteRule 301 /([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$3
```

But this breaks the entire site, giving me an error.....

I'd be really grateful if someone could help me out! I've been tearing my hair out over this!

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-content/ [NC]
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule /(?:[\d]+)/(?:[\d]+)/(.*)$ http://www.grvhi.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Okay, I think I just understood your problem.

Comment: @user1213425 try the update and also, by media you mean images right? and your `name-of-post` are not files right?

Comment: Yes - media is images and "name-of-post" are not files, no.

Comment: I'm now using: RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Redirect 301 /wpblog/ http://www.grvhi.com/

RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /(?:[\d]+)/(?:[\d]+)/(.*)$ http://www.grvhi.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: @user1213425 There was a mistake in it. I have just corrected it.

Comment: Well, I don't get an error anymore, but it's still breaking the links to my image files ("www.grvhi.com/wp-content/2012/02/......")

Comment: @user1213425 paste a full link to an image file here.

Comment: @user1213425 one more question. How are you handling the requests to posts?

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress